# I have to do many system() command line operations windows c++ MFC project, black boxes pop up, is there a way to suppress them?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, system, dos

I am writing an application for windows (7) that MUST run many "dos style" command line programs that can only be done using system calls..  when i run the system calls, big black boxes pop up and then disappear..  it makes the execution look super sloppy and much slower (i do like 25 of them and it looks very bad)  I want to hide them from the screen completely and have them just run...  is there a way to do this?   I have looked all over and I cant find anything about this..

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `system`, you can use `ShellExecute` and specify `SW_HIDE`. Alternatively, you can use `CreateProcess` and specify `DETACHED_PROCESS`. Here's a bit of demo code that creates a detached process of an executable you specify on its command line:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

void system_error(char *name) {
// Retrieve, format, and print out a message from the last error.
// The `name' that's passed should be in the form of a present tense
// noun (phrase) such as "opening file".
//
    char *ptr = NULL;
    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        0, GetLastError(), 0, (char *)&ptr, 1024, NULL);

    printf("\nError %s: %s\n", name, ptr);
    LocalFree(ptr);
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION p;

BOOL WINAPI die(DWORD reason) {
    TerminateProcess(p.hProcess, 1);
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    STARTUPINFO s;

    memset(&s, 0, sizeof s);
    s.cb = sizeof(s);

    if (!CreateProcess(argv[1], argv[2], NULL, NULL, TRUE,
        DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &s, &p))
    {
        system_error("Spawning program");
        return 1;
    }

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(die, TRUE);

    WaitForSingleObject(p.hProcess, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think to look for another mechanism besides system()..  I will try these out! Just looked up shellexecute and it might be pretty much a drop in replacement (plus i see it gives better returns than system call)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have dependencies between the tasks done by these command lines, you would be better off using CreateProcess or ShellExecuteEx, as these will allow you to WaitForSingleObject on the resulting process handle, as described [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip58.htm). So you can wait for a task to finish before kicking off the next one.